# How to properly draw sine wave?

Tags: ios, ios5, drawing, core-graphics

I need to draw sine wave (user chooses the frequency). My current approach is drawing lines between calculated points (point's that of course correspond to the sine wave's values). This works, but unfortunately only for lower frequencies. I think that the problem is that my sampling frequency (scale between my screen's coordinates and 1 unit) is about 50, so I can correctly draw sine wave with frequencies up to 25Hz (as per Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem).

Here are some screenshots so you can see what I am talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUDI5.jpg

So instead this incorrect graphs, when the frequency is too high, I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why not increase the sampling frequency so you're effectively sampling once per display point? That should immediately result in the kind of images you linked to. Here's one I just made: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13103695/sinedraw.png

Comment: @warrenm: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Here's the drawing loop. Note that the loop increment should be dependent on the device scale, but it's hard-coded here. https://gist.github.com/2925920